# JQuery Autocomplete SELECT event not fires

Tags: jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I am trying to use JQuery Autocomplete to search my website.

Problem that i am facing is,data appears correctly. But when i try to select any item. Nothing happens. Select Event do not fires.

My aspx code is below: Please help me if there is something wrong with this code.

My understanding is if i select any item from autocomplete result then "Selected" message should be appeared.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete("Search.ashx",
            {
                delay: 0,
                max: 30,
                min: 10,
                width: 300,
                formatItem: function (data, i, n, value) {
                    var temp = value.split(",")[3];
                    temp = temp.replace(" ", "-");
                    var result = "<table><tr><td> <a  href='" + value.split(",")[2] + "'><img style = 'width:40px;height:50px' src= images/mobiles/" + value.split(",")[1] + " /> " + "</a></td><td style='Vertical-Align:Top'> <a  href='" + value.split(",")[2] + "'>" + value.split(",")[0] + "</a></td></tr></table>";
                    return result;
                },
                select: function (e, ui) {
                    alert("selected!");
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete("Search.ashx",
            {
                delay: 0,
                max: 30,
                min: 10,
                width: 300,
                source: function (data, i, n, value) {
                    var temp = value.split(",")[3];
                    temp = temp.replace(" ", "-");
                    var result = "<table><tr><td> <a  href='" + value.split(",")[2] + "'><img style = 'width:40px;height:50px' src= images/mobiles/" + value.split(",")[1] + " /> " + "</a></td><td style='Vertical-Align:Top'> <a  href='" + value.split(",")[2] + "'>" + value.split(",")[0] + "</a></td></tr></table>";
                    return result;
                },
                select: function (e, ui) {
                    alert("selected!");
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```